# How can I use the Foundation Sites 5 grid CSS classes with the Cornerstone theme?

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, bigcommerce

Foundation Sites has CSS classes for a grid system. Instead of using these classes. the Cornerstone developers seem to use some SASS function called grid-column. I will occasionally need the default Foundation grid system when inserting content from the content manager. What I've tried so far is going into the theme.scss file in the assets folder and doing an import into the node modules folder where foundation/grid is kept. That didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think importing the grid only would work... the proper way to go should be:

- Including the whole Framework.
- As you only need the grid, edit the `_setings.scss` from the framework, disabling everything except for the grid (and please make sure you have the grid you want on settings, because default grid changed since 6.4).
- Including the new stripped down foundation into your project.

Hope this helps